# How to do Post Request from doPost servlet and get the response from callback url if there is no response it should internally redirect to other url?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, http-post

I want to do a form `POST` request to the url,in case of valid response callback URL should be called(or hit) else should be redirected to another page of the same application.
Eg : While doing online payment, when we click on pay on any site,it is redirected to our mentioned url,if the user ain't logged in, user is redirected to login page.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Error error = null;
    String jNo=request.getParameter("jNo");
    String emailId=request.getParameter("emailId");
    String mobileNo=request.getParameter("mobileNo");

    String callBackUrl=request.getParameter("url");
    HttpResponse httpRespnse=null;
    try {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://localhost:8080/abc/xyz.aspx");
        Invocation.Builder builder1 = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        Form form = new Form();
        form.param("jNo", jNo);
        form.param("emailId", emailId);
        form.param("url", callBackUrl);
        form.param("mobileNo", mobileNo");
        Response response1 = null;

        response1 = builder1.post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
        String responseXml = response1.readEntity(String.class);
        //PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter();
        System.out.println(response1.getStatus());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Issue in Request" + e);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        error = aadharProcess.getErrorMsg(Constants.ERR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope.I have predefined callback url where in expect the response,if the webservice i am posting the request to,the request data doesnt exist,it should internaly direct me to its page.

Comment: The callback url is for response,the response will be directed to callback url,like you do any activity on payment page and suppose u aint logged in,it redirects you to login page,like in same ways the domain on which i am hitting,in some cases it should redirects me to page,but in response i am getting html page.I should be redirected to that page.

Comment: Yes. I will only get response when i hit that URL sometimes,for specific request,i wont get response,in fact i will get a registration page in response,i dont want page in response i should redirected to that page.